# MVC WebApi Post generates 404 not found error on AZURE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have an MVC 4 web site with an ApiController which has a Post method.

Locally everything is running just fine, I can post successfully.
However after I deploy to Azure, I get a 404 message.

I have tried everything I found within the first 7 pages of google..

I've tried the famous solution of  adding the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests module also.

Please help...

Comment: Can you provide code and the name of your website?

Comment: The controller action code and the routes definition would be useful to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see some code, hard to speculate otherwise.

Azure however, manages its resources separately.  Are you pointing to the absolute path in Azure?  Referencing resources locally within azure doesnt work unless you've set up a virtual lan and are referencing another machine in that lan.